# swift 4 - for loops syntax error?

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I am working on a swift 4 game with spriteKit and have run up against an error while writing a loop shown below

```
override func sceneDidLoad()
    {
        super.sceneDidLoad()
        initialSize = size

        let numberWords = ["item1", "item2"]
        for items in numberWords {
            if defaults.integer(forKey: (items)) == 2{
                print(defaults.integer(forKey: (items)))
                print((items) , "still found")
              (items).texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square") //error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'texture'"

            }
        }

    }
```

The game has a list of items the player has to find and I am changing the SKTexture of each item once they are found. 
The print statements show the code is working as it should, but I also need to change the texture of the nodes, and am assuming I can add this line

```
(items).texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square")
```

which should loop through the nodes and change the texture...

but I get the error on that line

```
"Value of type 'String' has no member 'texture'"
```

The following code works fine when I hard code the item textures and the textures change as they should,

```
item1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square")
item2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square")
```

so I think the error is something to do with the syntax of the loop code?I am a beginner and this is my first post so forgive any confusion in my explanation.

update:

Ive worked it out I think, by using the SKspriteNodes "name" when I needed to use the name as a string

```
override func sceneDidLoad()
    {
        super.sceneDidLoad()
        initialSize = size
        item1.name = "item1"
        item2.name = "item2"

        let numberWords = [item1, item2]

        for items in numberWords {
         let itemName = (items).name
            if defaults.integer(forKey: itemName!) == 2{
                print(defaults.integer(forKey: itemName!))
                     print((itemName!) , "still found")
            (items).texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square")

       }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Obviously, since you are looping through `numberWords` array of strings, `items` is a string, which has nothing to do with `SKTexture`...

Comment: Why do you keep putting `items` in parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an array of items with `texture` property, not an array of strings, e.g.

```
for item in [item1, item2] {
    // do whatever you want here, e.g.
    item.texture = SKTexture(...)
}
```

Note, no quotes around `item1` or `item2`.